# create additional rows with different rules for different columns based on availability in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```py
   item_id  facility_id  actual_quantity  min_quantity           timestamp
0       11         1185                5             3 2022-01-11 00:00:00
1       12         1185                7             4 2022-01-11 00:00:00
2       23         1185                5             5 2022-01-11 00:00:00
3       34         1185                4             6 2022-01-11 00:00:00
4       56         1185                3             7 2022-01-11 00:00:00
5       67         1185                5             8 2022-01-11 00:00:00
6       12         1185                3             3 2022-01-11 01:00:00
7       23         1185                5             4 2022-01-11 01:00:00
8       34         1185               13             5 2022-01-11 01:00:00
9       45         1185               12             6 2022-01-11 01:00:00
```

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [11, 12, 23, 34, 56, 67, 12, 23, 34, 45],
                  'facility_id': [1185]*10,
                  'actual_quantity': [5, 7, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 13, 12],
                  'min_quantity': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                  'timestamp': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 01:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 01:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 01:00:00'),
                                pd.Timestamp('2022-01-11 01:00:00')]})
```

Here, in `timestamp` column, we have two unique timestamps. For `timestamp1 = Timestamp('2022-01-11 00:00:00')`, we have 6 unique item_ids and other columns related to those item_ids, whereas for `timestamp2 = Timestamp('2022-01-11 01:00:00')`, we have only 4 unique item_ids.

I want to achieve following:

Add rows in `timestamp2` with missing `item_id`s. Keep `facility_id`s for added rows same, i.e. `1185`, `actual_quantity` should be `0`, `min_quantity` should be same as there in `timestamp1` for that `item_id`.

Do similar thing for `item_id`s in `timestamp2` but not in `timestamp1`.

The `output_df` should look like this:

```py
    item_id  facility_id  actual_quantity  min_quantity           timestamp
0        11         1185                5             3 2022-01-11 00:00:00
1        12         1185                7             4 2022-01-11 00:00:00
2        23         1185                5             5 2022-01-11 00:00:00
3        34         1185                4             6 2022-01-11 00:00:00
4        56         1185                3             7 2022-01-11 00:00:00
5        67         1185                5             8 2022-01-11 00:00:00
6        45         1185                0             6 2022-01-11 00:00:00
7        12         1185                3             3 2022-01-11 01:00:00
8        23         1185                5             4 2022-01-11 01:00:00
9        34         1185               13             5 2022-01-11 01:00:00
10       45         1185               12             6 2022-01-11 01:00:00
11       11         1185                0             6 2022-01-11 01:00:00
12       56         1185                0             7 2022-01-11 01:00:00
13       67         1185                0             8 2022-01-11 01:00:00
```

What's the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Use a MultiIndex and reindex with `from_product`

Comment: @mozway oops didn't see it was closed

Comment: @enke I think you can leave your answer, always useful to have another example ;)

Comment: @mozway ok; but I don't understand how I was able to post at all when it was closed. It's happened to me twice now in the past week.

Comment: I think it might be a bug if you pre loaded the page before it was closed

Comment: Why has it been marked duplicate? Maybe better title can be suggested.

Comment: @ddejohn there might be a better duplicate, but it's a many times seen issue. I added another one

Comment: @ddejohn Actually how is the duplicate not answering the question? Combination of item_id/timestamp

Comment: @Mohammad I marked it duplicate because it is in substance. It doesn't look like you did the job of searching for similar problems and trying to apply the solutions to your issue. Check the answers in the duplicate links ;)

Comment: @enke are you using a mobile or blocking JavaScript? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: @ddejohn obviously you need to apply the product on the **unique** values. Here 7x2

Comment: @mozway Neither.

Comment: @ddejohn btw, an answer with MultiIndex: `cols = ['item_id', 'timestamp', 'facility_id'] ; df.set_index(cols).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[c].unique() for c in cols], names=cols)).fillna(0, downcast='infer').reset_index()[df.columns]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pivot` + `stack` + `fillna` + `reset_index`:

```
tmp = df.pivot(['item_id', 'facility_id'], ['timestamp'], ['min_quantity', 'actual_quantity'])
tmp['actual_quantity'] = tmp['actual_quantity'].fillna(0)
tmp['min_quantity'] = tmp['min_quantity'].ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1)
out = tmp.stack(level=1).reset_index()[['item_id', 'facility_id', 'actual_quantity', 'min_quantity','timestamp']]
```

Output:

```
    item_id  facility_id  actual_quantity  min_quantity           timestamp
0        11         1185              5.0           3.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
1        11         1185              0.0           3.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
2        12         1185              7.0           4.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
3        12         1185              3.0           3.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
4        23         1185              5.0           5.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
5        23         1185              5.0           4.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
6        34         1185              4.0           6.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
7        34         1185             13.0           5.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
8        45         1185              0.0           6.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
9        45         1185             12.0           6.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
10       56         1185              3.0           7.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
11       56         1185              0.0           7.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
12       67         1185              5.0           8.0 2022-01-11 00:00:00
13       67         1185              0.0           8.0 2022-01-11 01:00:00
```